# SQL joining table with two different alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am joining two tables for selecting records on basis of like query
my first table structure is like this
User Table==>

```
UserID fname Lname
```

Second Table
Agents Table ==>

```
Id AgentID ManagerId
```

where AgentID and ManagerID are foreign key,which contains UserID of my first table
I have to retrieve records on basis of first name of any one either manager or agent, I am writing this

```
select u.UserId,u.Fname,u.Lname,a.ManagerId from User u
a left join Agents a on u.UserId=a.AgentId
where u.fname like '%anyname%'
```

It is returning those Agents who have name AnyName, I want to return managers as well ie Join Agents table again with Users table but on ManagerId this time, how can I do this?

Comment: Try `union` of two select statements

Comment: It sounds like you want to join the two tables based on AgentsID at first and then ManagerID and then merge them. Is that right?

Comment: @ncdreamy Yes you get it correctly

Comment: @NikhilTalreja let me try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
select u.UserId,u.Fname,u.Lname,a.ManagerId from User u
a left join Agents a on u.UserId=a.AgentId
where u.fname like '%anyname%'

UNION

select u.UserId,u.Fname,u.Lname,a.ManagerId from User u
a left join Agents a on u.UserId=a.ManagerId
where u.fname like '%anyname%'
```